# background-size: cover bug in webkit

Tags: css, webkit

It looks to me like there is a bug in webkit, likely a rounding issue, that's causing the `background-size` property to fail to cover the entire are of an element when set to `cover`.

[image]

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/um4cQ/ (try resizing the result area if you don't see the red background showing through on either the left or top).

I've seen some references to the bug around the net, [some dating back to 2011](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=102477), but I've yet to hear anything from developers. More importantly for the time being, if there's a CSS workaround (without using javascript).

Has anyone found a viable workaround for this?

Comment: This isn't a solution - but if you're in a pinch you could use `background-repeat: repeat;` to make the issue slightly less noticeable.

Comment: `background-origin: border-box` seems to help, at least for thin borders as in this example.

Comment: Yeah, beat me to it...It looks like `border-box` makes the image cover behind the border, so the border is blocking the rounding error.

Comment: It's a good solution for this exact scenario but http://jsfiddle.net/um4cQ/1/. Now what?

Comment: The following workaround is possible, based on the similar idea of clipping the outer pixel of the image: http://jsfiddle.net/um4cQ/3/

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn: this works, it should be an answer not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I added the vendor prefix and it fixed some images, then I grouped the `background:` shorthand rule for the color and the no-repeat. This fixed some of the images, but not all, so I notice that it's related to the image dimensions you have, I used the same image (that was working) for all the images and it worked.

So the aspect ratio of your images has something to do here and I think it's because `background-size: cover;` is trying not to distort the image by messing up the aspect ratio.

[Here's my fiddle working](http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/QjHdf/)... just rework your images so they have an aspect ratio that will fit it's container properly.

Comment: Not on my machine (Chrome+Windows 8), but I'm now seeing the red showing through on the right or bottom instead of the left or top.

Comment: Are you saying that you have another version where you made all of the `figure` elements have the same background image?

Comment: Sorry for all the comments, but re-reading it it seems clear that that's what you're saying. Again another way to get around the issue in specific situations but what happens when you have no control over the images (uploaded content for example)?

Comment: I don't know how you can go around this if you don't have control over the crop of the image. However, I did another fiddle to show how squared images work for squared container http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/X8d47/ and to hopefully help you solve the issue.

Comment: This shows red at both the right and bottom for the first image for me.

Comment: My latest fiddle doesn't show any red at all, I'm on Chrome in PC.

Comment: I have two equally sized square boxes and two square images, 320x320 and 333x333 px. If the box is 48x48 the 320x image is correct and the 333x is wrong. If the box is 44x44 the 320x image is wrong and the 333x is correct. Weird bug in webkit indeed.

Comment: I think this bug is gone... I redid @pcguru's issue into a fiddle and didn't find the bug again. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/khL5S/

Comment: Oh I didn't think about it at the time, but I'm using the latest version of QtWebKit. It's still in there, at least in some form. If I have the time later I'll create a fiddle. https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKit